# Why wasn't Chewbacca's family arrested for their connection to him?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, chewbacca, star-wars-holiday-special

Chewbacca was well-known as a Rebel hero and enemy of the Empire. His immediate family, Lumpawaroo, Mallatobuck and Attichitcuk made no attempt to hide their relation to him or their existence from the Empire.

After the events of *A New Hope*, the Empire no longer even pretended to be democratic or respectful of sentient rights and the wookiees were treated as non-sentient slaves, meaning nothing would stop them from arresting the family members. So how come the Empire never arrested them to gather information on Chewbacca and Solo and/or punish them?

Comment: Just re-watched that wretched Star Wars Christmas Special. I almost died of cringe. [shudders]

Answer (score 6):

To the extent that anything in the "Star Wars Holiday Special" makes sense (which is not much of an extent), the only reasonable conclusion is that, as of the Life Day in question, Chewbacca's identity was still unknown to the empire.  For a time, at least, Itchy and company were still able to live unmolested at home.

Comment: What about after the special, though?

Answer (score 0):

From what we can discern, the **occupation of Chewbacca's home planet (Kashyyyk ? ) is not that harsh**.

From what we could see, Wookiees live in their homes, watch TV (or whatever SW substitute for this is ) , buy things, enjoy themselves and of course celebrate Life Day. Of course, Imperials sometimes barge in but this is far from life of slaves depicted in new Canon. Note that Imperial blockade is declared during the course of the movie, so things could get worse.

Did Empire knew about Chewbacca's identity ? In  "Star Wars Holiday Special" clearly they didn't. Imperial troops that search Chewbacca's house notice that he is missing (one male Wookiee missing) , but they do not know about his involvement in Battle of Yavin. This actually makes sense, since it is unlikely that Rebels (underground organization) would publicly announce real names of their heroes to the Galaxy thus endangering their friends and family. Yes, there is a medal ceremony at the end of New Hope, but it doesn't mean it was public.

Comment: The occupation of Kashyyyk depicted in the special also fails to match up with other works from the Legends continuity.